# WSL: why does Maven fail?

Tags: java, maven, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL (Ubuntu shell) in Windows. I installed Java and Maven and once I run Maven from Ubuntu shell I get:

```
$ mvn
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
```

Of course it doesn't happen once I run Maven from the "regular" Windows shell.

Do you know what I can do to resolve it?

```
Edit:

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.2, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-wsl2", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: How did you install java and maven? Does the java installation on itself work? What version of java and maven did you install? Does a project with maven wrapper work?

Comment: @Turing85 I edited the post. I hope the updated post answers your questions.

Comment: See [this maven bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maven/+bug/1930541). Can you try downgrading to java 11 or upgrading maven to a more recent version?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Turing85 for referring me to the bug.

I stayed with Java 17, but I downloaded Maven version 3.8.5.

You can see an explanation here how to do it:
https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-apache-maven-on-ubuntu-linux/